# sql query add 2 sum() results into single total column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have bee tryin to pull of a sql query in my workbench client, I am using two tables table `a > col1, col2` and `table b > colx, coly`. What I want to achieve is this `sum()` values in table `a > col a` and `sum()` values in table `b > coly`, next I want to add the results of both together.

SQL query

```
select

sum(table_a.col1) as 'result 1'
sum(table_b.coly) as 'result 2'
```

'Now how do I add these two result into new column and have all three columns visible e.g columns: result 1, result 2, total'

Comment: Please show your full query

Comment: *standard DBMS SQL* The question was what database product are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle,...)?

Comment: DBMS = database management system. The "standard" depends on your point of view

Comment: OK it is SQL Server, Obviously Does not look like MySQL :P

Comment: There is only one product that fails to report an error when the aliases are single-quoted ... And that isn't SQL-Server.

Comment: Damn, I was wrong, there are 2 products. And one of them [**is** SQL-Server.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13622)

Comment: @Tomazi Please run `SELECT @@VERSION AS 'version';` and tell us the output.

Comment: @Tomazi  *Obviously Does not look like MySQL*. It's **not obvious** at all http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b27ed/2. And if it's a SQL Server why your question is tagged with `mysql`??? Retag it appropriately please.

Answer (score 3):

```
select

sum(table_a.col1) as 'result 1'
sum(table_b.coly) as 'result 2',
sum(table_a.col1) + sum(table_b.coly) as Total
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the query that you want is:

```
select a.result1, a.result2, coalesce(a.result1, 0) + coalesce(b.result2)
from (select sum(table_a.col1) as result1 from table_a) a cross join
     (select sum(table_b.coly) as result2 from table_b) b;
```

The original structure of your query would cause a cartesian product between the two tables.